# How to get data from instance user_type by uid (Firebase flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter

[How to get data from instance user_type by uid (Firebase flutter)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NamaS.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable for your users collection

```
final CollectionReference _usersCollection =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users");
```

Query user document snapshot based on the userId value

```
final QuerySnapshot<Object?> usersQuery = await _usersCollection.where("uid",isEqualTo: userId).limit(1).get();
```

You can get your Map data from the document snapshot

```
if(usersQuery.length>0) {
  final Map<String, dynamic> userData =
      usersQuery.docs[0].data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
  return userData['userType']; // you can use the data as you wish here am returning it
}
// else do something when the data isn't available
```

Comment: In the database, I have a userType field. In general, I wanted to take its data so that I could work later, but I cannot make a method getter.

Comment: I have added the answer with explanation, you can ask me if anything is unclear. The codes might differ on the version of firebase you are using, so let me know about that incase of difficulties.

Comment: thanks for your answer, im gonna check tomorrow

Comment: sure, let me know if needed

Answer (score 0):

```
final _firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

// returns a list of user documents
final res = await _firestoreInstance.collection("user_type").get();
// returns the first user_type instance of the list
final firstUser = res.docs.first.data();

return firstUser['uid'];
```